# "I am a policeman, so I am able to see crime scenes" - does "being able to" here mean "having the right to do something"?

Tags: meaning

**Example 1**

> I am a policeman, so I am able to/am allowed to see crime scenes.

**Example 2**

> I am a lawyer, so I am able to/am allowed to meet families who need legal help.

I am wondering whether "be able to" can mean "having the right to do something".

For example, "seeing crime scenes" doesn't sound like a skill or ability to me.

The meaning is more like "having the right to see crime scenes."

By contrast, "Be allowed to" definitely means having the right to do something.

Comment: The last sentence is a false assumption. The doorman at a gig might be a friend who allows you to enter without a ticket, but you still don't have the right to be there. The Lexico entry for [able](https://www.lexico.com/definition/able) mentions nothing about having any rights: it's more to do with skills and opportunities.

Comment: Your two examples are about people who need to do things as part of their job, rather than being allowed to as a privilege. I would suggest _have the opportunity to_.

Answer (score 2):

Many words in English have multiple definitions.

The word "able" usually refers to a skill or capability. But yes, sometimes it is used to mean a right or privilege. For example, Collins English Dictionary gives as definition 3 for "able", "qualified, competent, or authorized to do some specific act". Note "authorized".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, “can” and “be able” are frequently used to denote “be permitted” or “be authorized.” That of course is also one of the meanings of “may.”

Some people have called a rule of grammar what is really a recommendation on usage, namely to use “can” only for physical or mental ability. I personally like that more restricted usage because it makes clear when permission is the topic. But it is not close to being a universal usage.

For some etymological background, see

https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/when-to-use-can-and-may